# Retreive Domain name from a PHP variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a PHP config file which I retrieved from SSH. 
Here is the sample config file in PHP :

```
<?php
$url_root='https://google.fr';
$document_root='/usr/share/nginx/html';
```

The command I use to retrieve the url :

```
grep -oE '\$url_root=.*;' conf.php | tail -1 | sed 's/$url_root=//g;s/;//g'
```

Output:

```
'https://google.fr'
```

But I expect to retrieve only `google.fr`

Then I need to implement this command line into ssh like :

```
domain=$(ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@127.0.0.1 '
    COMMAND HERE;
')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomodate for unpredictable data (aka you can find complete urls including other routes / files and not only domain names) I would go for:

```
your_str='https://google.fr/somedir/someotherdir/index.html'
echo $your_str | cut -d'/' -f3
```

Output:

```
google.fr
```

In your ssh command:

```
 'grep -oE '\''\$url_root=.*;'\'' conf.php | tail -1 | sed '\''s/$url_root=//g;s/;//g'\'' | cut -d'\''/'\'' -f3'
```

Comment: In my side, I have always a single quote at the end of the result. `google.fr'`

Comment: Hi @executable

I wrote it in my answer, please check.

Comment: Sorry but I just saw that my escaping was not optimal. Rule is: You need to pass the quotes to the remote shell so that the comment is treated as a string. The simplest way is to put the whole remote command in single quotes. If you need a single quote in that command, use '\'' correcting now.

Comment: Ok please try now and let me know... Be sure that it starts and ends with a single quote alone.

Comment: Well, I have an unexpected end of file error `bash: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ''bash: -c: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file` Here is my command https://justpaste.it/75tfz

Comment: If I use the command : `grep -oE '\''\$url_root=.*;'\'' conf.php | tail -1 | sed '\''s/$url_root=//g;s/;//g` I have an unfinished command

Comment: Please use 'grep -oE '\''\$url_root=.*;'\'' conf.php | tail -1 | sed '\''s/$url_root=//g;s/;//g'\'' | cut -d'\''/'\'' -f3'

Comment: Getting close. Now I have the following : `google.fr'` with a single quote

Comment: I have finally removed quotes using : `tr -d \'\"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DOMAIN_NAME=$(grep -oE '\$url_root=.*;' conf.php | tail -1| sed "s/\$url_root='//g;s/^[a-z]*:\/\///g;s/';//")
echo "Domain name is: $DOMAIN_NAME";
# ssh user@$DOMAIN_NAME etc...
```

The portion of code `s/^[a-z]*:\/\///g;` looks for one or more occurrences of a-z followed by :// and removes it if it exists.

Comment: How to I insert into the ssh command without getting the error of escaping some quotes